# Do different pronunciation of detail /dɪˈteɪl/ /ˈdiː.teɪl/ have the same meaning and usage?

Tags: pronunciation

On [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/detail), the word "detail" has two different American pronunciations: /dɪˈteɪl/ and /ˈdiː.teɪl/. Do they have the same meaning and usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## /dɪˈteɪl/ vs /ˈdiː.teɪl/

**/ˈdiː.teɪl/** is a *noun* while **/dɪˈteɪl/** is a *verb*.

It's a very common pattern. Disyllabic nouns are usually stressed on the first syllable while disyllabic verbs are on the second syllable.

/ˈdiː.teɪl/ has primary stress on its first syllable so it's a noun. /dɪˈteɪl/ has primary stress on its second syllable, it's therefore a verb.

You will also observe this in the following noun/ verb pairs:

- INcrease (noun) - inCREASE (verb)
- REcord (noun) - reCORD (verb)
- CONduct (noun) - conDUCT (verb)
- CONflict (noun) - conFLICT (verb)

It usually happens in disyllabic words.

Here's a list of noun/ verb pairs: [World English Blog](https://www.google.com/amp/s/worldenglishblog.com/verb-and-noun-pairs-examples/amp/)

As always, there may be exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, all of it in the US and most in the US northeast, "detail" as a noun, meaning a specific item (as in "it is an important detail that the colors match") and "detail as a verb (as in "He offered to detail the car for an extra $50.") are pronounced in **exactly*** the same way, with no change of stress or vowel sound at all. I do not believe that noun can be reliably distinguished from verb in this case by pronunciation.